# Macbook Air 2017 Black Dots On Screen

Tags: macbook-pro, display, screen

Recently I observed some black dots on the bottom of the screen on my MacBook Air 2017. They appeared suddenly. I don't know what's going on with it! Do I have to replace the entire display because of it? And lastly, is my display going to die soon?

Any idea what's that, and how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please include the screenshots directly in your post so people can see it without clicking an a link.

Answer (score 0):

Your 2017 MacBook Air has "stage lights". After shutting your MacBook off, it can be easily fixed by using a P5 screwdriver to remove the bottom case, unplugging the battery, and carefully removing the display cable for dusting / cleaning with canned air. Make sure you dust the port and the cable before carefully plugging back in.

Follow steps 1 - 3, then skip to 19 since we are only reseating the display cable and not unplugging the camera and removing the entire display. Hope this helps.

https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Air+13-Inch+Early+2017+Display+Assembly+Replacement/135928